# htaccess rewrite block - target specific directory (for PreRender.io caching)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prerender

I would like to modify the below ModRewrite block to only be triggered when the URL starts like this:
`http(s)://my-website.com/n/` ....

The rewrite is used to send the (angular) page to PreRender for caching so search engines can index it. The whole angular portion of the site lives under `/n/` so that is all I need to cache

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

        # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
        RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(index\.php)?(.*) http://service.prerender.io/%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$3 [P,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd want to add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /n/
```

like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /n/

# Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(index\.php)?(.*) http://service.prerender.io/%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$3 [P,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I see you're from PreRender - in testing this, I removed a 2 pages from the cache, 1 that will get filtered out and one that should make it through. Then I hit those 2 pages in the browser... from that point, how long should a cache take? I have waiting 10-15 mins so far ...

Comment: If you are accessing the ?_escaped_fragment_= URL, it should instantly cache them. Feel free to email us at support@prerender.io if you'd like us to check into this more for you.